# How to retrieve particular data on clicking record from arraylist (Sqlite database)in Android??

Tags: android

i have show records in array-list on one layout.now i want to show like....if i click on particular record then that particular record must show on layout..i.e on next or another  layout fully.i used Sqlite database.

```
lvUsers.setClickable(true);


    lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {

          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
          {

            Object o = lvUsers.getItemAtPosition(position);
            UserBO obj = (UserBO) o;
            Toast.makeText(Select.this, "Record Selected= "+obj.getId()+" "+obj.getName()+" "+obj.getAge()+" "+obj.getDate()+" "+obj.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              

            Intent i = new Intent(Select.this,ShowProfile.class);
                startActivity(i);   

         }


        });
```

Thanks in Advance----

Comment: paste your code here then i can explain you what to do

Comment: now i want to click on listview record and want to view it..how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setOnItemClickListener to the ListView as follows

```
lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

implement the interface

```
OnItemClickListener
```

and then add the following override method

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

}
```

In the above method the parameter position indicates the the position of the item has been clicked in ListView

By using this you can get the clicked item and pass it to the next Activity.

Comment: hi...i have edited my code..and written  as per your suggestion.i am getting data record on toast message. but when i clicked on item from list it showing Forced Close......please let me know how to remove this error.